# Negative Scores by a Single Individual

Tags: discussion, voting

Reading posts on Stack Exchange you see people get negative responses to what could be a valued answer. I can only presume people who do this are IMHO pretty uptight, given an answer has been proposed in all honesty that looks like it is intended to help others.

By letting an individual give a negative, Stack Exchange leaves itself open to abuse, with valid comments from other quarters slating Stack Exchange.

As Stack Exchange professes to be committed to good answers, should they not counterbalance this with the attitude that a negative response cannot be generated without the backing of others in the community?

I.e. an individual gives a negative vote which may or may not be generated by a peevish response to an answer given to a particular question, however a negative response given by up to, say 5 people, pretty much negates this type of behaviour and makes the negative value of -1 for 5 votes a valid response from a community.

I did mention positive scores too, as we see in Stack Exchange where a visible positive vote has been given others will follow with more positive votes on that one answer, despite there being better answers posted afterwards.

What are your thoughts on both positive and negative responses to questions and answers on Stack Exchange? and do you believe that individual votes truly represent a community in the best light, or would it not be better to have a number of votes cast, before a score can be given?

Comment: Your vote should reflect how useful a given post *actually is*, not how useful the author *intended* it to be.

Comment: So why would the site be better off if small numbers of people were unable to express their opinions on the quality of a post?  Everyone is already free to give more weight to a post with numerous up/down votes over a post with only a few; why do you think readers can't be trusted to judge for themselves whether or not to consider the votes of a small number of users?

Comment: I have seen users apparently get minus votes for apparently no reason. Now this can either be from someone who has acted in such a way which is more to do with personality rather that how a question is asked or answered, or ir could be an honest answer of someone who has not shot from the hip, but sat down and given it some thought.  An individual sees a minus vote, then without thinking adds to that minus vote. Does it make the vote valid, not really it just shows lack of forethought.

Comment: Just because you don't understand why someone voted the way that they did doesn't make their vote invalid.  If their opinion conflicts with the other members of the community, then when others vote it will outweigh that vote and readers will see that it's a minority opinion.

Comment: Sorry but I doubt that, I saw a -4 vote within 1 minute of the question posted, with no comments made. I do respect those that do make a comment honestly and would give a reason for a minus or indeed a positive vote, but those who vote and leave no comment fail the community itself. Do individuals on here then oppose democratic voting ?  given it is an aggregate of many votes with a single outcome, or are they saying that all individuals are honest and that they are not influenced by prior votes given.

Comment: So apparently *you* are the one here going against the community's opinion, and therefore, by your own logic it is your own opinion that we should be striving to prevent others from seeing.  That you're now saying that your opinion should be heard over a consensus from the rest of the community is a pretty sharp reversal of opinion.  Why do you think people disagreeing with your opinion is opposing democratic voting?  You're the one saying that everyone else is wrong and shouldn't be allowed to express their opinions because it conflicts with yours, which is...let's say, not so democratic.

Comment: Not at all, I have said that individuals who comment and vote either way shows they have courage of conviction, whereas those who just vote and leave no feedback are suspect straight away.  Pointless trying to twist things around to your way of thinking, by denying others free thought and comments about an honest question. It can only be a concensus of a community, where there is a majority vote, not a minority one, Unless you consider for some reason that less than 10  is a majority ?

Comment: So you're in the habit of justifying your votes when you go to your local elections, and you feel that your vote shouldn't be counted if you don't have the "conviction" to explain your vote to everyone else?  You consider any place that doesn't require a public statement explaining every vote to be a proper democratic institution?

Comment: G - we explicitly do not require anyone to leave a comment on a down or up vote. It is nice when they do, as it can help turn a post around, but as some people respond badly to a downvote it protects those who do downvote from recriminations.

Comment: [Why isn't commenting mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s)

Answer (score 4):

Individual votes are the only way to do this - and because we have large communities, the aggregate wins.

Yes, there is a fastest-gun-in-the-west effect, but in reality it doesn't change a good post to a bad post or vice versa. What we encourage is to vote on whether the post is good, answers the question or provides value in some way... to the voter. That's how it works. Everyone has their own opinion of a post and can vote accordingly - very democratic.

Requiring 5 votes to equal 1 vote just reduces the value of votes to a fifth, but doesn't change the process at all.

Comment: Just my point, individuals are not an aggregate vote, but individuals that for some silly reason give a negative vote. My view  would be not to vote unless you found the question or answer to be totally wrong. When it is a question asked honestly, why should the question be voted down, other than by those who don't like honest questions.

Comment: Have you read the guidelines? If the post is not good, voting down is the fastest way to get it off the front page. While upvotes are good to reward a good post, we don't want bad ones hanging around. And yes, edits are good when a post is salvageable, but if a post is not good, we don't want it on the site - doesn't matter the intent behind it.

Comment: Individuals voting **does** become an aggregate.

Comment: A post of this nature is not good or bad, it is an honest question asked. To try to hide a question because you don't like it, is exactly what poor politicians do constantly. Lets cover it up because we may not like honest answers. @Rory true, however in a democratic state it is an aggregate vote that has a single outcome and is hidden from view. You can certainly bet that if a polling booth was showing how many votes a party had received, individuals would be swayed to vote in a particular way. This is quite evident from the Trump vote and facebook swaying peoples votes in the U.S.A elections

Comment: Honesty is almost irrelevant G. It has to be a good question for future visitors and the individual. Otherwise why do you think it belongs on the site? My vote is not because I like or dislike the topic or anything like that. It's on whether it meets site requirements, is on topic etc.